# What is my mistake in applying the AC-3 algorithm on this problem?

Tags: constraint-satisfaction-problems, norvig-russell

I want to apply AC-3 algorithm to the following CSP:

There are two variables $A$ and $B$.

Domain of $A: \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\} $

Domain of $B: \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\} $

The constraints:

$$A < B $$
$$B = A^2 $$

I'll apply the AC-3 algorithm depicted in [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, 4th edition](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/index.html) (figure 6.3)

Step 1. By converting constraints to arcs, our arc queue will be as following:

$$A < B $$
$$B > A $$
$$B = A^2 $$
$$A = \sqrt{B} $$

According to the algorithm, when processing an arc such as $(X_i, X_j)$, if the domain of $X_i$ was changed, all the arc that their destinations are $X_i$ and their source are a neighbor of $X_i$ must be add to the end of the arc queue **except for** $X_j$. Since we have only two variables, therefore I think we do not need to add any new arc to the queue.

Step 2. processing the arc queue:

- Applying $A < B$ reduces the domain of $A$ to $ \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
     6, 7, 8 \} $.
- Applying $B > A$ reduce the domain of $B$ to $ \{ 1,
     2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 \} $.
- Applying $B = A^2$ reduces the domain of $B$ to $ \{ 1, 4, 9 \} $.
- Applying $A = \sqrt{B} $ reduces the domain of $A$ to $ \{ 1, 2, 3 \} $.

So, at the end, the domain of $A$ is $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and the domain of $B$ is $\{1, 4, 9\}$.
But this answer is not correct. Since for $1$ belongs to the domain of $B$, there is no element in the domain of $A$ such that $ B < A $ satisfies.

It is obvious that the domains of the arc consistent CSP is as following:

- Domain of $A: \{2, 3\} $
- Domain of $B: \{4, 9\} $

What is my fault?

I think adding arc $(X_j, X_i)$ as well as other neighbor arcs $(X_k, X_i)$, when the domain of $X_i$ is reduced by applying arc $(X_i, X_j)$, leads to correct answer.